# python + django+ EmailMultiAlternatives Template' object has no attribute 'encode

Tags: python, django, email, send

I am sending an email by following method:

```
EmailMultiAlternatives()
```

When the send() method is called; I get error in somewhere base class.

```
lib/email/encoders.py
'Template' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

> Exception Location:   C:\Python27\lib\email\encoders.py in encode_7or8bit, line 73
>
> Python Executable:    C:\Python27\python.exe

error path:

```
>   return msg.send(fail_silently)

C:\Python27\lib\email\mime\text.py in __init__
>  self.set_payload(_text, _charset)

C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py in set_payload
>   self.set_charset(charset)

C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py in set_charset
>  cte(self)

C:\Python27\lib\email\encoders.py in encode_7or8bit
>  orig.encode('ascii')
```

can anyone have an idea about this error?

**Update**
using the following code helped me solve my problem.

```
fail_silently=True

t = get_template(template_name)
html_part = t.render(context)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                                 t,
                                 sender,
                                 recipients,
                                 bcc=bcc)
msg.attach_alternative(html_part, "text/html")

return msg.send(fail_silently)
```

Comment: It looks like a `Template()` object is being sent; not a string. The template wasn't rendered to a string.

Comment: i was using the same code in 1.3 django, i upgraded it today and i am getting this error. 

here is my email code. see update.

Comment: How did you solve this error?

Comment: you can see the working code under update heading.

Answer (score 0):

While using the `get_template` method from django.template.loader I was getting the following error

Error: **AttributeError at 'Template' object has no attribute 'splitlines'**

Solution which worked for me

`from django.template.loader import render_to_string`

Comment: please update with full solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Template object cannot be used directly in the email, it needs to be rendered with a context to generate a string that can be used, for example:

```py
context = Context(dict(some_key=some_value))
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
  from_email="admin@example.com",
  reply_to="admin@example.com",
  subject="Example email subject"
  body=Template(template_body).render(context),
  to="recipient@example.com",
)
if html_email:
  html_body = Template(html_template).render(context)
  email.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html")
email.send()
```

A link to the related Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types